# How to get user to type in a specific word to get a specific response in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input, user-input

I'm trying to make a simple quiz in python to check if the user is able to determine who my friends are. It is still not complete but basically I want the program to give a certain response if the user enters a certain input that matches my list. For example, the first question is "Who is my BEST friend?". If the user enters "Mariah", I want the program to tell them they are correct and then move on to the next question. My problem is when I enter that, the response should check for the match and it doesn't match up even for the correct input. It completely ignores if my `if` statement for getting the "you're correct!" statement and jumps directly to the `else` statement: "sorry you're incorrect". How do i fix this?

```
list = ["Mariah", "Julian", "Gabbi"]
variable = input("do you know my friends? yes or no? ")
if variable.lower() == "yes":
    print("oh really... ")
    variable2 = input("what is my best friend's name? ")
    if variable2.lower() == list[0]:
    print("you are correct, but she's not my only friend")
    else:
        print("sorry you're WRONG!")
elif variable.lower() == "no":
     print("i thought so...")
else:
    print("that answer didn't make sense")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the input to lower case but not the list value

try

```
if variable2.lower() == list[0].lower():
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is wrong on the code snippet you shared, but I assume that might just be formatting for the question.

Also, try not to use variable names that override keywords or defined functions in python, for example `list`.

Additionally, you compare `variable.lower()` to the list. So you are comparing a forced lowercase string, to the name `'Mariah'`, which has a capital letter.

You can fix this by

```py
friends = ["Mariah", "Julian", "Gabbi"]
variable = input("do you know my friends? yes or no? ")
if variable.lower() == "yes":
    print("oh really... ")
    variable2 = input("what is my best friend's name? ")
    if variable2.lower() == friends[0].lower():
        print("you are correct, but she's not my only friend")
    else:
        print("sorry you're WRONG!")
elif variable.lower() == "no":
    print("i thought so...")
else:
    print("that answer didn't make sense")
```